# glmmLasso R Error:Error in grad.lasso[b.is.0] <- score.beta[b.is.0] - lambda.b * sign(score.beta[b.is.0])

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models, lasso-regression

I am trying to use `glmmLasso` to run a multilevel logistic regression model, as I believe I am getting some wonky results due to sparse data bias. My outcome variable is a binary (0, 1) variable and my grouping variable is ID. Here is my code:

```
m1 <- glmmLasso(outcome ~ c.AGE + c.BSS + c.negative.emotion + 
   c.PSI_Total + c.MEPS_Ratio + c.OTT_Ratio + c.AAQ_Total + 
   c.BHS_Total, rnd=list(ID=~1 + c.negative.emotion), 
   lambda=100, data=data.set.3, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

This is the error I am receiving:

> Error in grad.lasso[b.is.0] <- score.beta[b.is.0] - lambda.b * sign(score.beta[b.is.0]) : 
>     NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(y, Mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

I am unsure why I am getting this error. I did [see another post about this error on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484977/glmmlasso-error-and-warning) but I was unable to use the fix for my data. There are no `NA`s in the dataset. I've attached the dataset in CSV format [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e0JdEfWuuZHJRayk8BHVqPsssmONPtuN/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: can you add a link to the other StackOverflow post here?  That might be useful ...

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484977/glmmlasso-error-and-warning

Comment: Still having trouble identifying a fix! Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can't reproduce at the moment. With glmmLasso 1.5.1 in R 3.6.2 on Windows, I get a couple of warnings (Cluster vble should be specified as a factor, random slopes are not standardized back) but no error ... (after converting `ID` to a factor, the first warning goes away)

Comment: Can you post package/R version (or sys.Info() output)?

Comment: I am a Mac user, glmmLasso version 1.5.1 in R version 3.6.0 (macOS High Sierra 10.13.5). I believe I still got this warning after removing random slopes - so might be worth trying? I also had to specify outcome as a factor (unsure if that is an issue). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi @NA_Psych, I had the same error and changing response from factor to integer helped. You can try out.