# Error in Z_aktuell * D : non-conformable arrays

Tags: r

Can anyone figure out why I get the error below after running the following code?

```
library(haven)
library(survival)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(glmmLasso)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
library(discSurv)
HH<- as.data.frame(read_dta("https://www.stata.com/data/jwooldridge/eacsap/recid.dta") )
HHC <- contToDisc(dataShort = HH, timeColumn = "durat",  intervalLimits = 20,equi = TRUE)

dtLong<-dataLong(dataShort = HHC, timeColumn = "timeDisc",
                 eventColumn = "cens",timeAsFactor = FALSE)
                       formula.1<-y~factor(black)+factor(alcohol)
                             family<-binomial(link = "logit")
                                      lambda <- 20
                                         penal.vec<-20
                                            next.try<-TRUE

BIC_vec<-rep(Inf,length(lambda))
Deltama.glm2<-as.matrix(t(rep(0,3)))#coefficients + Intercept
Smooth.glm2<-as.matrix(t(rep(0,20)))
j<-1;test.step<-1;

glm2 <- glmmLasso(formula.1,  
                      rnd = NULL,family = family, data = dtLong, lambda=lambda[j],final.re=T,switch.NR=F,
                      control = list(smooth=list(formula=~-                     1+as.numeric(timeInt),nbasis=20,spline.degree=3,
                                                 diff.ord=2,penal=penal.vec[test.step],start=Smooth.glm2[j,]),
                                     method.final="EM", print.iter=T,print.iter.final=T, 
                                     eps.final=1e-4,epsilon=1e-4,complexity="non.zero",
                                     start=Deltama.glm2[j,]))
```

Iteration  41
Final Re-estimation Iteration  9Error in Z_aktuell * D : non-conformable arrays

when I change Deltama.glm2<-as.matrix(t(rep(0,3))) to Deltama.glm2<-as.matrix(t(rep(0,2)))

I get the error

Iteration  1Error in grad.lasso[b.is.0] <- score.beta[b.is.0] - lambda.b * sign(score.beta[b.is.0]) :
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

I have tried to remove the starting values as suggested on [glmmLasso error and warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484977/glmmlasso-error-and-warning) without success

Answer (score 0):

Switching from R version 4.2.2 to 3.6.0 solved the issue. Seems there is a compatibility issue between glmmlasso and the newer  versions of R.